# Given the path of property key, how to retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Consider I've an object `myObj`
And I've a string representing the path to some property inside it: `foo.bar`

What is the best way to get it from my object?

If I knew the string ahead I would do `myObj.foo && myObj.foo.bar` to get it safely

A simple solution would be to split the string `'foo.bar'.split('.')` and than loop over it.

But i'm sure there is a better way

---

It's a duplicate of other question. they provided a great solution:

given a `path` and an `obj` get the property value this way

`path.split('.').reduce((o, i) => o[i], obj)`

Answer (score 0):

> A simple solution would be to split the string `'foo.bar'.split('.')` and than loop over it.

Yep, that sounds like the best way. You can create a helper method that does exactly this, but there's nothing built in to the language or standard libraries to make things simpler than this.

```
function getFromPath(obj, path) {
 var current = obj;
 for(let piece of path.split('.')) {
  current = current[piece];
 }
 return current;
}
```

Usage:

```
getFromPath({foo: {bar: "hello"}}, "foo.bar"); // "hello"
```